# how to get which character is get deleted on backspace in android

Tags: android, autocomplete, backspace

I am working with android 2.2.

How to know which character is get deleted on backspace when editing text in custom auto complete in android.

```
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode,KeyEvent msg){  
     if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL)
     {
        // how to find here which character is get deleted
     }
     return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String prevText = "";
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode,KeyEvent msg){  

     if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL)
     {
        int pos = myEditText.getSelectionStart();
        char c = prevText.charAt(pos);
        // c is deleted
     }
     prevText = myEditText.getText.toString();
     return false;
}
```

Comment: one more query for this ques. How to find color code of character which is get deleted on backspace.

Answer (score 1):

You can use add a [`TextWatcher`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to AutoCompleteTextView with [`addTextChangeListener(TextWatcher)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29).

You don't need to listen to `onKeyUp()` the various TextWatcher methods inform you if the user is adding or removing text.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is just keep last character that you type

```
int lastKeyCode;
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode,KeyEvent msg){  
     if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL)
     {
        // print lastKeyCode here
        // how to find here which character is get deleted
     }
     lastKeyCode = keyCode;
     return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Try this, working for me

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        String initialChar = null;
        int initCursorPosition = 0;

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int after) {
                char addedChar = 0;

                int finalCursorPosition = editText.getSelectionStart();
                if (finalCursorPosition - initCursorPosition > 0) {
                    addedChar = charSequence.charAt(finalCursorPosition - 1);
                    Log.d(TAG, "onTextChanged added: " + addedChar);
                   //added char

                } else {
                    char delChar = initialChar.charAt(initCursorPosition - 1);
                   Log.d(TAG, "onTextChanged deletedChar: " + delChar);
                   //deleted char
                }

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int after) {
            Log.d(TAG, "textChange beforeTextChanged: " + charSequence);
            Log.d(TAG, "textChange cursorPosition: " + editText.getSelectionStart());
            initialChar = String.valueOf(charSequence);
            initCursorPosition = editText.getSelectionStart();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(Edittext).setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
{
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {
            if(event.getKeyCode()==67)
            {
                if((EditText).getText().toString().length()>0)
                {
                               int pos = (Edittext).getSelectionStart();
                               Char c = (EditText).getText().toString.charAt(pos);
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationontext(),String.valueOf(c),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        }   
            return false;
        }
    });
```

I think it helps you

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very late answer, but this would be effective for future users.

First the `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL` doesn't work for soft keyboard in latest android versions, so you have to create a custom `EditText` to handle that.

So we'll create a class to handle all null type in `LatinIME`

```
import android.text.SpannableStringBuilder;

public class EditableAccomodatingLatinIMETypeNullIssues extends SpannableStringBuilder {
    EditableAccomodatingLatinIMETypeNullIssues(CharSequence source) {
        super(source);
    }

    public static CharSequence ONE_UNPROCESSED_CHARACTER = "/";

    @Override
    public SpannableStringBuilder replace(final int
                                                  spannableStringStart, final int spannableStringEnd, CharSequence replacementSequence,
                                          int replacementStart, int replacementEnd) {
        if (replacementEnd > replacementStart) {
            super.replace(0, length(), "", 0, 0);

            return super.replace(0, 0, replacementSequence, replacementStart, replacementEnd);
        }
        else if (spannableStringEnd > spannableStringStart) {
            super.replace(0, length(), "", 0, 0);

            return super.replace(0, 0, ONE_UNPROCESSED_CHARACTER, 0, 1);
        }

        return super.replace(spannableStringStart, spannableStringEnd,
                replacementSequence, replacementStart, replacementEnd);
    }
}
```

Then we'll go ahead to create another class to handle the `InputConnection` of the custom `EditText` to be created

```
import android.os.Build;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.Selection;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection;

public class InputConnectionAccomodatingLatinIMETypeNullIssues extends BaseInputConnection {

    Editable myEditable = null;

    public InputConnectionAccomodatingLatinIMETypeNullIssues(View targetView, boolean fullEditor) {
        super(targetView, fullEditor);
    }
    @Override
    public Editable getEditable() {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
            if(myEditable == null) {
                myEditable = new EditableAccomodatingLatinIMETypeNullIssues(
                        EditableAccomodatingLatinIMETypeNullIssues.ONE_UNPROCESSED_CHARACTER);
                Selection.setSelection(myEditable, 1);
            }
            else {
                int myEditableLength = myEditable.length();
                if(myEditableLength == 0) {
                    myEditable.append(
                            EditableAccomodatingLatinIMETypeNullIssues.ONE_UNPROCESSED_CHARACTER);
                    Selection.setSelection(myEditable, 1);
                }
            }
            return myEditable;
        }
        else {
            return super.getEditable();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deleteSurroundingText(int beforeLength, int afterLength) {
        if((Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) // && (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19)
                && (beforeLength == 1 && afterLength == 0)) {
            return super.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL))
                    && super.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL));
        }
        else {
            return super.deleteSurroundingText(beforeLength, afterLength);
        }
    }
}
```

Then creating the custom `EditText`

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputConnection;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

public class CustomEditText extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText {

    public CustomEditText(@NonNull @NotNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomEditText(@NonNull @NotNull Context context, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomEditText(@NonNull @NotNull Context context, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
        InputConnectionAccomodatingLatinIMETypeNullIssues baseInputConnection =
                new InputConnectionAccomodatingLatinIMETypeNullIssues(this, false);

        outAttrs.actionLabel = null;

        outAttrs.inputType = InputType.TYPE_NULL;

        outAttrs.imeOptions = EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE;

        return baseInputConnection;
    }

}
```

So in your `.xml` file, you can say something like

```
<your.package.name.CustomEditText
    <!set all required attributes-->
    />
```

Now in your java code, you have to listen for the `Backspace` click event and get the character to be deleted before it's deleted.

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener(){
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
            int selStart = editText.getSelectionStart();
            int selEnd = editText.getSelectionEnd();
            //incase if some text in the textbox are selected, selStart and selEnd will
            //return the positions of both selected ends and you can get the text(s) deleted.
            
            //check if the selEnd is at 0, and if true, then there's not point going further
            if(selEnd == 0)
                return false;
            
            //if there is no texts selected, then reduce selStart by one to get the text to be deleted
            if(selStart == selEnd)
                selStart -= 1;
            
            String text = editText.getText().toString();
            //now this will get you char or chars to be deleted
            String charDeleted = text.substring(selStart, selEnd);
            
            //So before returning false to deleted the char,
            //let me answer the question asked also on the
            //comment section in Bobs' answer
            //which is to find the color code of the deleted char
            //Note, this is for only a single char, if you want to
            //handle for multiple chars, then you'll have to split the
            //deleted chars into an array and get the color codes for each
            
            //This will get all HTML text within the deleted char including the color code
            String htmlText = Html.toHtml((Spanned) editText.getText().subSequence(selStart, selEnd));
            
            //Now you have to use a HTML parser, and I'm using JSoup
            //Don't forget to implement the JSoup library into your project
            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlText, "UTF-8");
            
            //Here I'm selecting a SPAN html tag, hoping that the char should be in a SPAN
            //If it's in a FONT or any other tag, then you select the tag instead and also
            //the attribute containing the color code
            Elements element = doc.select("span");
            //Attribute containing the color code for SPAN is the STYLE
            String style = element.attr("style");
            //So the style string would be giving you something like "color:#AABBCC;"
            //Where #AABBCC is the color code of the deleted char
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
edittext.addTextChangeListener(new TextWatcher{
@override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){
     String changedtext = s.toString();
}

@override
public void  beforeTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}

@override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
});
```

Comment: The reason of down vote is you have added correct listeners but not completely answered the question e.g where ru u doing deletion or checking deletion .

Comment: Answer is just to let person know that, he can use this to achieve his requirements.